# Weka Snowball Stemmer giving errors

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath, weka

I have a program like this -

```
import weka.core.stemmers.SnowballStemmer;

public class TestProject{
public static void main(String[] args) {    
   String testString = "shortly";
      SnowballStemmer stem = new SnowballStemmer();   
      String text = stem.stem(testString);
      System.out.println(text);
   }
}
```

This program executes and I get the following output -

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in    CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?

shortli
```

My question is how to remove those 5 lines of errors that are printed when the program executes?

I am not using any database.

Thank You,

Comment: I tried *exactly* what you've pasted with weka version 3.6.6, but I don't get the jdbc error. The output from the console I got is `shortlyStemmer 'porter' unknown!`

Comment: @Jasonw You have not added the snowball.jar file to your class path as mentioned [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Stemmers#Snowball%20stemmers). PS: I am still getting the jdbc error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right thing to do because if adding `snowball.jar` initialize the database connection, probably snowball need that connection for a reason. But anyway, here is a workaround if you want that five lines of errors not to be printed.

- make a copy of DatabaseUtils.props, you can find it from `weka.jar /weka/experiement/DatabaseUtils.props`
- place this properties file in your classpath. For example in eclipse, place it at the root of the project.
- commented out **all** lines start with jdbcDriver.
- added a line `jdbcDriver=`

When I execute the class file with the properties file in place, this is the output.

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
shortli
```